# Spinner from shinycssloaders package loads before pressing the action button

Tags: r, shiny, spinner, shinycssloaders

I am creating a shiny app with some tabs and I am using the `shinycssloaders` package in order to show a spinner AFTER pressing the `actionButton`. I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60738023/spinner-loading-before-action-button-is-pressed) because I was having the same problem... I followed the solution that it was given to the post, but as I my app is different (it has `tabPanel`s, it doesn't work properly, the spinner still apears).

For example, if you click on "Show the plot" in the first tab (selection) and then you want to want to do the log2 transformation o calculate the square root (3rd tab, calculations), before clicking the `actionButton` the spinner appears and the plot updates. It happens the same when you want to change the titles (2nd tab).

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks very much in advance

The code:

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinycssloaders)
new_choices <- setNames(names(mtcars), names(mtcars))


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("My shiny app"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("Selection",
                  selectInput("x_axis", "Choose x axis",
                            choices = new_choices),
                  
                  selectInput("y_axis", "Choose y axis",
                              choices = new_choices),
               
                  hr(),
                ),
                  
          tabPanel("Titles",
                    hr(),
              
                    textInput(inputId = "title", "You can write the title:",  value = "This is the title"),
                    textInput(inputId = "xlab", "You can re-name the x-axis:",  value = "x-axis...."),
                    textInput(inputId = "ylab", "You can re-name the y-axis:",  value = "y-axis ...."),
          
                  ),
      
      
          tabPanel("Calculations", 
                    hr(),
                    
                    checkboxInput("log2", "Do the log2 transformation", value = F),
                    checkboxInput("sqrt", "Calculate the square root", value = F),
                   
                   )

          ),
      actionButton(inputId = "drawplot", label = "Show the plot")
    
      ),
              
              # Show a plot of the generated distribution
              mainPanel(
               # plotOutput("plot") 
                uiOutput("spinner"),
                
              )
      )
    )


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  

  data <- reactive({
    mtcars
  })
  
  
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    data <- data()
    if(input$log2 == TRUE){
      data <- log2(data+1)
    }
    if(input$sqrt == TRUE){
      data <- sqrt(data)
    }
    return(data)
    
  })
  
  
  
  observeEvent(input$drawplot, {
    
    output$spinner <- renderUI({
      withSpinner(plotOutput("plot"), color="black")
    })
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      Sys.sleep(3)
      ggplot() +
        geom_point(data = filtered_data(),
                   aes_string(x = input$x_axis, y = input$y_axis)) +
        xlab(input$xlab) +
        ylab(input$ylab) +
        ggtitle(input$title)
    })
    
  })

  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it OK like this? I'm not sure to understand all your requirements. To avoid the spinner at the start-up, I use a `conditionalPanel`. In the server code, I did some changes. It is not recommended to define some `output` inside an observer.

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinycssloaders)

new_choices <- setNames(names(mtcars), names(mtcars))


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("My shiny app"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(
          "Selection",
          selectInput("x_axis", "Choose x axis",
                      choices = new_choices),
          
          selectInput("y_axis", "Choose y axis",
                      choices = new_choices),
          
          hr(),
        ),
        
        tabPanel(
          "Titles",
          hr(),
          
          textInput(inputId = "title", "You can write the title:",  value = "This is the title"),
          textInput(inputId = "xlab", "You can re-name the x-axis:",  value = "x-axis...."),
          textInput(inputId = "ylab", "You can re-name the y-axis:",  value = "y-axis ...."),
          
        ),
        
        
        tabPanel(
          "Calculations", 
          hr(),
          
          checkboxInput("log2", "Do the log2 transformation", value = F),
          checkboxInput("sqrt", "Calculate the square root", value = F),
          
        )
        
      ),
      actionButton(inputId = "drawplot", label = "Show the plot")
      
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.drawplot > 0",
        style = "display: none;",
        withSpinner(plotOutput("plot"))
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    mtcars
  })
  
  
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    data <- data()
    if(input$log2 == TRUE){
      data <- log2(data+1)
    }
    if(input$sqrt == TRUE){
      data <- sqrt(data)
    }
    return(data)
  }) 
  
  gg <- reactive({
    ggplot() +
      geom_point(data = filtered_data(),
                 aes_string(x = input$x_axis, y = input$y_axis)) +
      xlab(input$xlab) +
      ylab(input$ylab) +
      ggtitle(input$title)
  }) %>% 
    bindEvent(input$drawplot)

  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    Sys.sleep(3)
    gg()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I didn't know about the existence about `bindEvent`! Thanks very much, it is what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You need to `isolate` the expressions that you don't want to trigger the rendering event inside `renderPlot`

```r
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinycssloaders)
new_choices <- setNames(names(mtcars), names(mtcars))


ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("My shiny app"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            
            tabsetPanel(
                tabPanel("Selection",
                         selectInput("x_axis", "Choose x axis",
                                     choices = new_choices),
                         
                         selectInput("y_axis", "Choose y axis",
                                     choices = new_choices),
                         
                         hr(),
                ),
                
                tabPanel("Titles",
                         hr(),
                         
                         textInput(inputId = "title", "You can write the title:",  value = "This is the title"),
                         textInput(inputId = "xlab", "You can re-name the x-axis:",  value = "x-axis...."),
                         textInput(inputId = "ylab", "You can re-name the y-axis:",  value = "y-axis ...."),
                         
                ),
                
                
                tabPanel("Calculations", 
                         hr(),
                         
                         checkboxInput("log2", "Do the log2 transformation", value = F),
                         checkboxInput("sqrt", "Calculate the square root", value = F),
                         
                )
                
            ),
            actionButton(inputId = "drawplot", label = "Show the plot")
            
        ),
        
        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            # plotOutput("plot") 
            uiOutput("spinner"),
            
        )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    
    data <- reactive({
        mtcars
    })
    
    
    filtered_data <- reactive({
        data <- data()
        if(input$log2 == TRUE){
            data <- log2(data+1)
        }
        if(input$sqrt == TRUE){
            data <- sqrt(data)
        }
        return(data)
        
    })
    
    
    
    observeEvent(input$drawplot, {
        
        output$spinner <- renderUI({
            withSpinner(plotOutput("plot"), color="black")
        })
        
        output$plot <- renderPlot({
            Sys.sleep(3)
            ggplot() +
                geom_point(data = isolate(filtered_data()),
                           aes_string(x = isolate(input$x_axis), y = isolate(input$y_axis))) +
                xlab(isolate(input$xlab)) +
                ylab(isolate(input$ylab)) +
                ggtitle(isolate(input$title))
        })
        
    })
    
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Read more about shiny reactivity and isolation: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/isolation.html

Comment: @Iz100 Thanks very much! However, I still don't understand what isolation does. What does it mean "dependency"?

Comment: "dependency" means events that will trigger current reactive expression